# Katalon Windows App / WinAppDriver error ‘Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.’

Tags: automated-testing, katalon, winappdriver

I'm using Katalon Enterprise 8.0.5 and WinAppDriver 1.2.1.
I'm trying to automate this Microsoft application - 'Dynamics 365 (preview)' - despite the name it is supposedly the finished article: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-dynamics-365-preview/9n0rwz9kzzt8#activetab=pivot:overviewtab
Using Katalon, I am unable to use any of the Windows app record functionality, as I get lots of these errors: "Exception: Encountered element sharing the same runtimeId 42.1246640.4.5.1.619"and the WinAppDriver stops, with message "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException." There appear to be lots of elements with duplicate IDs, as if I use Object spy and try to check an element, I get two matches, even using locator methods (like ID or Name).
Where to go, is this a MS problem?
Thanks Dan

Comment: It appears to be a Katalon problem. Have you contacted them? Perhaps they have some support page where they answer questions. In general, if the tool is buggy, don't use it. It will probably bring you more trouble than solution.

Comment: Hi, yes I've asked the question but not had solution just yet. Wanted some help to tell whether it's the driver, Katalon or possibly even the app itself. Other apps have been working ok

Comment: Hi - to add, the following applications crash when I attempt to capture element details from the Dynamics desktop app:
- Inspect.exe
- WinAppDriverRecorder
- AccessibilityInsights.io
This means I would also be unable to automate the desktop through Appium for example, since I would have no way of capturing elements. There is a suggestion that the offline capabilities is the cause of duplication. I guess options are to wait for Microsoft to 'fix' the app (they may not regard it as broken) or find a non-Appium way of automating a desktop perhaps?